# Completely restart/reload declarative class with dynamic functionality in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, oop, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy + SQLite3 for creating multiple databases based on user input. When initializing a new database, the user defines any number of arbitrary features and their types. I wrote a `DBManager` class to serve as an interface between user input and database creation/access.

Dynamically "injecting" these arbitrary features in the declarative model (the `Features` class) is working as expected. The problem I have is when the user wants to create a second/different database: I can't figure out how to completely "clear" or "refresh" the model or the `declarative_base` so that the user is able to create a new database (with possibly different features).

Below is a minimal reproducible example of my situation:

`src.__init__.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker()
Base = declarative_base()
```

`src.features.py`

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from src import Base

class Features(Base):
    __tablename__ = "features"
    features_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @classmethod
    def add_feature(cls, feature_name, feature_type):
        setattr(cls, feature_name, Column(feature_type))
```

`src.db_manager.py`:

```
from typing import Optional, Dict

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from src import Base, Session
from src.features import Features


class DBManager:
    def __init__(self, path: str, features: Optional[Dict] = None) -> None:
        self.engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{path}')
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
        self.features = features
        if self.features:  # user passed in some arbitrary features
            self.bind_features_to_features_table()
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def bind_features_to_features_table(self):
        for feature_name, feature_type in self.features.items():
            Features.add_feature(feature_name=feature_name, feature_type=feature_type)
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import String, Float, Integer
from src.db_manager import DBManager

# User wants to create a database with these features
features = {
    'name': String,
    'height': Float,
}
db_manager = DBManager(path='my_database.db', features=features)

# ... User does some stuff with database here ...

# Now the user wants to create another database with these features
other_features = {
    'age': Integer,
    'weight': Float,
    'city_of_residence': String,
    'name': String,
}
db_manager = DBManager(path='another_database.db', features=other_features)
```

After executing the last line, I'm met with: `InvalidRequestError: Implicitly combining column features.name with column features.name under attribute 'name'.  Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly.` The error wouldn't occur if the feature `name` did not appear on both databases, but then the feature `height` would be brought over to the second database, which is not desired.

Things I tried but didn't work:

- call `Base.metadata.clear()` between `DBManager` instances: same error
- call `sqlalchemy.orm.clear_mappers()` between `DBManager` instances: results in `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'instrument_attribute'`
- call `delattr(Features, feature_name)`: results in `NotImplementedError: Can't un-map individual mapped attributes on a mapped class.`.

This program will be running inside a GUI, so I can't really afford to exit/restart the script in order to connect to the second database. The user should be able to load/create different databases without having to close the program.

I understand that the error stems from the fact that the underlying `Base` object has not been "refreshed" and is still keeping track of the features created in my first `DBManager` instance. However I do not know how to fix this. What's worse, any attempt to overwrite/reload a new `Base` object will need to be applied to all modules that imported that object from `__init__.py`, which sounds tricky. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Razvan yes, kinda - I wrote an answer explaining what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to define the `Features` declarative class inside a function, `get_features`, that takes a `Base` (declarative base) instance as an argument. The function returns the `Features` class object, so that every call essentially creates a new `Features` class as a whole.

The class `DBManager` is then responsible for calling that function, and `Features` becomes a instance attribute of `DBManager`. Creating a new instance of `DBManager` means creating an *entire new class* based on `Features`, to which I can then add any arbitrary features I'd like.

The code looks something like this:

```
def get_features(declarative_base):
    class Features(declarative_base):
        __tablename__ = "features"
        features_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

        @classmethod
        def add_feature(cls, feature_name, feature_type):
            setattr(cls, feature_name, Column(feature_type))

    return Features


class DBManager:
    def __init__(self, path, features):
        self.engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{path}')
        Session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session()
        base = declarative_base()
        self.features_table = get_features(base=base)
        if self.features:  # user passed in some arbitrary features
            self.bind_features_to_features_table()
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def bind_features_to_features_table(self):
        for feature_name, feature_type in self.features.items():
            self.features_table.add_feature(feature_name=feature_name, feature_type=feature_type)
```

It definitely feels a bit convoluted, and I have no idea if there are any caveats I'm not aware of, but as far as I can tell this approach solved my problem.